# Google Maps - Getting the info window to show?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've currently got a Google Map showing successfully and it looks like this:

[image]

I want it to show with the info window showing by default, like this example:

[image]

I read this page: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#InfoWindows but that seemed to only explain how to make an info window with your own custom content. I just want to show the info like the example above where you see on many sites.

Comment: If you're using the Maps API V3, what content do you plan on using to fill the infowindow?  Or do you mean that you want a source for the content, in addition to wanting the infowindow to be open by default?

Comment: Try using the [Client Location API](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/documentation/#ClientLocation) or Google Search to find the business, then populate your info window with this information?

Comment: do u want to open infowindow when map loads or on click of specific marker?

Comment: Client Location API has been deprecated. I would look instead at HTML5 Geolocation: http://html5demos.com/geo

Comment: @andresf.. I want to fill it with the exact kind of contact like I have showed in the second image. The business info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Places API:

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/

Or the Places Library (part of the Google Maps JS API):

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/places.html

You'll parse the response in JS and then set the content of the infowindow as needed.  Note that scraping content from business listings (at least on Google's domains) to fill your infowindows is against the terms of service.

Here is a basic example:

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/place-details.html

Answer (score 0):

This is how I've done it on map on my site (opens this type of the popup by default): in the initialization function I wrote

```
map.openInfoWindow(new GLatLng(coordinates), 'html code for the text in window');
var baseIcon = new GIcon(G_DEFAULT_ICON);
baseIcon.shadow = "http://www.google.com/mapfiles/shadow50.png";
baseIcon.iconSize = new GSize(20, 34);
baseIcon.shadowSize = new GSize(37, 34);
baseIcon.iconAnchor = new GPoint(9, 34);
baseIcon.infoWindowAnchor = new GPoint(9, 2);
```

But this one is only for the map on your website. For the general data in Google, available to everyone, it is not so simple, of course ) For your business to appear on the map you have to go here
http://www.google.com/local/add/businessCenter
or read this link http://support.google.com/adwords/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=143287

Comment: It's not for my business so those links you gave don't suit my needs. It's for a site which lists many businesses, I just want to show the info box with the business info when the map loads. :)

Comment: @Brett         So, the map is on your site? read this http://www.svennerberg.com/2009/09/google-maps-api-3-infowindows/

Comment: Yeah...... I know how to add the infoWindows with your own content but I want to add the info windows with the business info exactly like in the second image.

Comment: @Brett         I'm not sure what is your problem in that case.. Just call infowindow.open(map, marker); when the map is initialized and that's it. Content of that infowindow can be anything you want.

Comment: But my question is..... how do I retrieve that business information and display it like that in the window!?

Comment: @Brett         Where do you want to retrieve it from? Do you want to put there your own information or something else?