# How to open the infoWindow google map is using?

Tags: maps, infowindow

I have a Goole map in a contact page in which i would like to show the infoWindow used on Google map.

Go to that link : [Gmap](https://maps.google.be/maps?rlz=1G1ACAWCFRBE358&q=copyland%20ixelles&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=fr&sa=N&tab=wl)

And click on the marker. A info window should appear.

My question is : How do I make the same thing append on my Website ?

Ps : I know how to build a google.maps.InfoWindow object, but i don't want to create the html myself.

Answer (score 0):

This part of the Google Map's Docs explains this: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#InfoWindows

Define your lat long coordinate

```
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);
```

Set your map otions

```
var mapOptions = {
  zoom: 4,
  center: myLatlng,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}
```

Initialize your map

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
```

Set the content for your infowWindow

```
var contentString = '<b>Set content for infowindow here in HTML<b>';
```

Intialize your infoWindow with the content string.

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: contentString
});
```

Place your marker at the previously defined marker on the above defined map

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng,
    map: map,
    title:"Uluru (Ayers Rock)"
});
```

And finally just bind the 'click' event on the marker to the infowindow you created.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
  infowindow.open(map,marker);
});
```

Comment: Yes i know, but this way i've got to create the html by myself. I just want to use the one prebuild by google...

Comment: Oh, if that is what you want you simply have to use the Places API to accordingly set the content of your infoWindow. The same question has been asked before here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8994877/1415352

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Yeah thanks it seems ok, but how do i get the reference of my Place ? : /

Comment: I guess you need Google's Geocoding API for that. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/

I haven't used this particular API though.

Comment: Thanks, that helped but the problem is not solved. I can't figure out how to find my place's reference and use it in the place api.

It used to be so simple with the iframe...